# Dynamic class object logging in python

Tags: python, class, logging

I'm using logging conf file. Trying to get different file for each user. It works fine, creates the files with the names of the users I'm passing in. But then when I'm trying to create log entrance for each user by:
'user1.logging.info(...)', and 'user2.logging.info(...)', both entrances goes into the log file of user2. Why?

logging.conf file:

```
[loggers]
keys = root, user

[handlers]
keys = consoleHandler, userFileHandler

[formatters]
keys = Formatter

[logger_root]
level = DEBUG
handlers = consoleHandler

[logger_user]
level = DEBUG
handlers = consoleHandler, userFileHandler
qualname = user
propagate = 0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class = StreamHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = Formatter
args = (sys.stdout,)

[handler_userFileHandler]
class = FileHandler
level = DEBUG
formatter = Formatter
args = ('%(logfilename)s', 'a+')

[formatter_Formatter]
format = %(asctime)s [%(funcName)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

class:

```
class User:
    """" Users instantiation class """
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.logger = self.Logger()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.email)

    def Logger(self):
        """ Users loggers instantiation """
        logging.config.fileConfig('log/logging.conf', defaults={'logfilename': 'log/{}.log'.format(self.email)})
        logger = logging.getLogger('user')
        logger.info('info log for: {}'.format(self.email)) # That entrance works fine
        return logger
```